# file_get_contents synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, file-get-contents

Today I came across one situation.

I am using `file_get_contents` to get token from a file for a user.

```
$data=file_get_contents("http://example.com/aaa.php?user=tester&akey=abcdef1234");
$dec=json_decode($data,true);
$tokenid=$dec['message']['result']['tokenid'];
```

Using the token i will call another file to get details;

```
$data=file_get_contents("http://example.com/bbb.php?user=tester&token=".$tokenid);
```

the problem is sometimes i am  not getting tokenid,  after refreshing the page  i get it.

There is no problem in aaa.php its working fine.

I doubt whether php is not waiting for the response of the `file_get_contents` of token before going to the second `file_get_contents(asynchronous);`

I have tried with curl too but sometimes  I am  not getting tokenid. I haven't faced these kind of issues.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is definitely synchronous. PHP in general is synchronous.

Comment: "not getting" how? `$data` comes out blank? contains something other than json, causing `$dec` to be null? f_g_c is NOT asynchronous and will block until it receives data or the underlying network stuff times out.

Comment: many times i received json with tokenid but sometimes i received null.

Comment: Checking `$data` before handing it to `json_decode` would help to diagnose.  See the 'return values' parts of the documentation.

Comment: If you *sometimes* receive NULL, but other times don't, it's simply because your endpoint returns different data. It's not your fault - it's the end point fault. Unless randomness is programmed your program should print the same every time.

Comment: I check $data,  out of 10 times one time i didnt get any json output

simply null

Comment: @h2oooo I am not clear of endpoint?? 

can you please explain in detail

Comment: is there anything i need to change in php.ini...

is there any error in the code??

Comment: The real question you need to ask is if the `$data` string is not returned correctly or if it is and the string returned simply is not decoded because it is invalid.  Your code does not evaluate that well enough to provide an answer.

Comment: sorry @Barmar but in my case it seems asynchrone. If i use only "$inputs = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);" my $inputs are empty, i'm forced to add this other line "$inputs = json_decode(json_encode($inputs));" and it works !

Comment: @bArraxas I don't see how that could be, and it certainly doesn't have anything to do with synchronous vs asynchronous.

Comment: @Barmar you right, finally i think my problem was because using "header_remove('Set-Cookie');" more bottom in my code. By removing it, i had never have the problem again. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not a question of synchronous vs. asynchronous.  But as is debugging is pretty impossible.  Try something like this.  The `die` statements are ugly but illustrates the validation you might want to incorporate...

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://example.com/aaa.php?user=tester&akey=abcdef1234");
if (empty($data)) die('Failed to fetch data');

$dec = json_decode($data, true);
if (is_null($dec) || $dec === false) die('Failed to decode data');

$tokenid = isset($dec['message']['result']['tokenid']) ? $dec['message']['result']['tokenid'] : null;
if (is_null($tokenid) die('Token ID is not set');

//...

$data=file_get_contents("http://example.com/bbb.php?user=tester&token=".$tokenid);
```

A guess might be your token sometimes contains 'special' characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: i tried your method sometimes i am receiving 'Failed to fetch data';

but after refreshing I am receiving the data.

Comment: in my case Token will always be numerical value.

but aaa.php page is not having any issues.every time i run aaa.php via brower  its giving json output

Answer (score 5):

`file_get_contents` is synchronous. You can get `FALSE` sometimes because of different reasons like network fail, DNS fail etc.

Use curl instead: it's [faster](http://mdb9.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/file_get_contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance/) and more customizable. You can [wait for good response recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178917/1113207) if you need 100% success.

Comment: I think that is inaccurate that you can get a `NULL` back from `file_get_contents`.  We need to be clear that `false  !== NULL`

Comment: You're right, `FALSE` of course. But I think it doesn't change the essence of the answer.

Comment: Update the answer then

Answer (score -1):

**the best way to waiting for file_get_contents, i hop that help you.**

```
if ($result = file_get_contents("http://exemple.com", false)) {
 echo $result; // for exemple
}
```