# PHP file_get_contents is asynchronous?

Tags: php, asynchronous, file-get-contents

I read that file_get_content is synchronous, but when I tried the code below I dont' think so :

```
$url = "http://foo.com";
$a = array("file11.php", "file2.php", "file3.php");
foreach ($a as $file)
{
    $final = $url . "/" . $file;
    print "Calling $final ...";
    $res = file_get_contents($final);
    if ($res)
        print "OK";
    else
        print "ERR!";
    print "<br>";
}
```

Each file executes some complex tasks, so I know the minimal excution time of any script, but this code runs very fastly and seems not to wait each request ! How can I wait for each file request?
Thanks :)

Comment: Errrrr, what? Explain what you mean, because it is extremely confusing what you're saying. What does `Each file spends at least 30 seconds` mean? What do you expect to see here? What are you actually seeing? How are you measuring anything? And why does this make you believe that file_get_contents() is asynchronous rather than the expected synchronous behaviour?

Comment: PHP is not asynchronous and file_get_contents *certainly* isn't. The problem you're having is unrelated to this.

Comment: @MarkBaker : http://foo.com/file11.php do some complex tasks, when I run it alone (from its url) I have to wait for a pretty long moment (not exactly 30s :) to have the result ! It's the same thing for file2.php and file3.php !

Comment: @Bulk : I found something different : First comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105075/file-get-contents-synchronous-or-asynchronous)

Comment: @user You might want to check the answers on the question you refer to, instead of the question itself. Bulk is absolutely right on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is definitely synchronous. So if you say that the code exits after a few seconds, while it should be a lot longer, then you probably have a problem with the code.

Try to wrap this code in a try {} catch. And print the error. See what it says.

```
Try { code here } catch (Exception $e) {  }
```

Also, most default settings in the php.ini for MAX_EXECUTION for a script is 30 seconds. After that it will exit on a fatal timeout error too. Check the setting in your php.ini and adjust it to your needs.

**Edit:**

Gathering your comments, I now assume you are trying to execute the php files you are referring to. This makes your question very confusing and the tags just wrong.

The code you use in your example only reads the contents of the file, so it's not executing anything. Which explains why it returns so fast, while you expect it to take a while.

If you want to execute the referred php files, approach it like this:

```
Include_once( $final );
```

Instead of opening the contents.

Comment: No exceptions catched :( There are no problems with the script runnig, no timeout error ...

Comment: So what output do you get? And the timeout, if it occurs, is actually a fatal, so it won't get cought in your handling.

Comment: Oh and you are not actually are running the php code that resides in the called php files... You are just getting it's contents. I assume you know that right?